# Почему изменение копии int'а не всегда меняет исходный int?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеются два примера, в рамках которых мы работаем с копией int-переменной. В первом примере изменение копии int'а меняет исходный int:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    Person(String s, int i){
        name = s;
        age = i;
    }
}
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Person p1 = new Person("John", 22);
        Person p2 = new Test().change(p1);
        System.out.println(p1.name + " " + p1.age);
        System.out.println(p2.name + " " + p2.age);
    }
    private Person change(Person p){
        Person p2 = p;
        p2.age = 25; 
        return p2;
    }
}
```

Итоговый результат:

```
John 25
John 25
```

то есть теперь p1.age также указывает на '25'. Тем не менее, во втором случае:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x = 10;
        int y = new Test().change(x);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(у);
    }
//В примере параметром является int x, что немного путает с толку. Может быть любой буквой.
    int change(int x){
        x = 12;
        return x;
    }
}
```

получаем итоговый результат:

```
10
12
```

то есть x по-прежнему указывает на '10'. С чем может быть связано такое различие?

Благодарю.

Comment: В первом случае никакой копии инта не делается. Во втором случае переменная типа int копируется два раза.

Comment: Но каким образом создается тогда Person p2? Разве это не измененная копия Person p1?

Comment: Нет. Это вторая ссылка на тот же самый объект. Проверьте: `System.out.println(p1 == p2);`

Comment: Странно, при попытке добавить код, выдает syntax error on tokens.

Comment: Значит, не туда добавляете.

Comment: Пардон, еще только учусь. Где имеется ошибка? http://i.imgur.com/o5njVrJ.png

Comment: Похоже на невидимый символ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44048/discussion-between-dmitry08-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С Вашего позволения, приложу комментарий с 'тостера':

Вариант 1: Смотри, ты создал в куче обьект с адресом "пусть будет 111", после чего ты присваеваешь этот адресс 2ому обьекту. Получается, что обьект 2 имеет тот же адрес "111", потом ты в этом адрессе "111" меняешь возраст на 25, соответственно оба обьекта становятся с адрессом 111.

Вариант 2: х = 10 это локальная переменная, если ты ее передаешь дальше, то, чтобы ты с ней не делал - в мейне она останется 10. Ты ее изменил на 12 в функции change и 12 она только там, нигде более, после чего ты возвращаешь просто значение 12, которое инициализирует переменную y.